# Multiple similar GUI windows java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, observer-pattern

I am working with JFrame and observers. I have a functioning GUI with multiple buttons and functions.

I am trying to create a button which opens a new window, that is exactly the same as the main window. All changes in any window, should be automatically updated to all open windows.

Any help how to begin?

Comment: Well I assume you have a class extending your JFrame right ? How about in your action listener for your button you simply instantiate your same class again.

Comment: 1) Use Model-View-Control or MVC design pattern, 2) use a factory method to create your sub-views (or as you call them, windows), and 3) give each sub-view the same shared model object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General suggestions:

1. Use Model-View-Control or MVC design pattern,
2. use a factory method to create your sub-views (or as you call them, windows), `createWindow(Model model)`, and
3. give each sub-view the same shared model object.